# Regarding Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression

Tags: angularjs, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, express

i am implementing a angular+node js app.I am new to this.
I have define a href as `<li><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" href="/#/login">Login</a></li>`   in the html page and have defined the route as

```
.when("/login", {
      templateUrl: '/app/ng/modules/home/partials/login-partials-view.html',
      controller: 'LoginController'
    })
```

I am getting issue as

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: /#/login

Can anyone please suggest me whats causing the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You put a wrong url : it is #/login

```
  <li><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" href="#/login">Login</a></li>
```

If you want .state method do this :

```
  .state('login', {
    url: "/login",
    templateUrl: "/app/ng/modules/home/partials/login-partials-view.html"
})
```

Then you can use ui-sref like this :

```
<li><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" ui-sref="login">Login</a></li>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.If I add the above URL it gives me Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #/login issue.Can you please tell me what I am missing.Its invoking the controller But doesn't pop up the login window.Do i need to add something in the code?

Comment: You can also use state method and do ui-sref="login"